# Where are the sources for phantomjs 1.9.19?

Tags: node.js, facebook, build, phantomjs

I am trying to build [phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) version `1.9.19` for an `armv8-a` processor. However, when I checked out the project's [github page](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/releases) the latest `1.9.x` release I found is `1.9.8`.

Where can I find the sources for `1.9.19`?

## background

Version `1.9.19` is required by facebooks [osquery](https://github.com/facebook/osquery). Since it does not come pre-build for `arm` I have to manually build it and its dependencies. Currently it breaks with `info phantomjs@1.9.19 Failed to exec install script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PhantomJS 1.9.19. The *phantomjs* NPM package is supposed to be an easy way to install PhantomJS and its version usually corresponds with the PhantomJS version it contains, but it started to go off the rails from version 1.9.8 onwards (which actually contains PhantomJS 1.9.7). The maintainer messed up.

PhantomJS 1.9.8 is the last version of the 1.x branch. You can compile that and create your own *phantomjs* package with a version that you need.